# Visual Studio 2008 Unresponsive When Opening JavaScript Files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm starting a new ASP.NET project that I'm trying to use some jQuery with, but whenever I try to open .js file (blank or containing a few lines of javascript) in Visual Studio (SP1), it often hangs; showing the .js filename in a new tab, but the actual text editor window showing whatever was drawn to the screen before opening the .js file. Eventually, after closing and re-opening, it will open in the text editor, but the font is always something like 10pt Arial and the colors do not match what I have set in Visual Studio options. Even after changing this in VS options, the next re-launch of Visual Studio yields the same results.

Has anyone else experienced hang, unresponsiveness, wonkiness from Visual Studio with JavaScript files? Any advice?

Comment: No, this has never happened to me. Have you tried deleting all .suo and .user files in the solution? Also, in the "Tools-->Import and Export Settings" dialog, try exporting your current settings (as a backup), selecting "Reset all settings", and then see if this happens again. You can restore your settings later from your backup file. Good luck!

Comment: First thing I tried, unfortunately to no avail, thanks though!

Comment: Sorry to ask a standard Microsoft PSS question: Have you applied Sp1?

Comment: Yes, I'll be sure to update my post reflecting that. Thanks!

Comment: would you upload you HTML please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing Visual Studio 2008 and SP1 and this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the [hotfixes](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads) will help and solve your problem.

Comment: I've looked through that list, saw nothing that applies to my situation. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PowerCommands for Visual Studio installed?  If so, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921894/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-i-open-a-javascript-file)

Comment: No. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my previous install after installing sp1 and the hotfix for getting javascript intellisense on jquery.  At the time I had only the standard install and had to install sp1 separately. After trying a reinstall doing the standard install then sp1 then the jquery hotfix it still had the same problem.  I ended up having to get a visual studio sp1 disk and then it worked.

Comment: I'm currently reinstallating Visual Studio 2008, SP1, then the -vsdoc hotfix. If this doesn't work, I'll try to find an SP1 disk.